# How to set up Docker development environment on Debian?

Tags: containers, docker

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://docs.docker.com/contributing/devenvironment/) in order to build Docker from source but I'm stuck with a banal error:

```
root@blackberry:/home/manuel/mygit/docker# make build
docker build -t "docker:master" .
/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 127
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is due to the fact that on Debian-like systems the `docker` command is replaced with `docker.io`.

I tried to solve the problem setting up:

```
root@blackberry:/home/manuel/mygit/docker# alias
alias docker='docker.io'
```

But I had any luck :-(

Can you please tell me how to how to set up Docker development environment on Debian-like system? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have docker installed and I'm using it without problems with the command `docker.io`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker requires Docker in order to build from sources. Do you have docker installed? If the alias fails, you can try to copy the binary to 'docker' somewhere in your path.
If you don't have docker installed yet, you can either install it via `apt` or even more simple: directly download the binaries: http://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/.

Comment: I have docker installed and I'm using it without problems with the command `docker.io`

Comment: You alias is on you shell and make uses /bin/sh. Just make sure 'docker' is available in your path (mv, ln -s, cp, etc..)

Comment: I added in `/usr/bin` the soft link `ln -s docker.io docker` and now the installation process is working, thanks!